# bootstrap-datetimepicker <div datetimepicker> duplicates every time I reload the page with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am using a bootstrap-datetimepicker on my page with many date components that I submit to db and refresh the form using Ajax. Everything seems to work fine until I noticed that if I do about 10 updates, my browser freezes. I came to discover that the datetimepicker div duplicates itself every time I update a record and reloads the form with ajax. see below an example where I use 4 datetimepickers

When the page loads first:

```html
<div class="datetimepicker datetimepicker-dropdown-bottom-right dropdown-menu" style="left: 173.283px; z-index: 1010;"></div>

<div class="datetimepicker datetimepicker-dropdown-bottom-right dropdown-menu" style="left: 647.467px; z-index: 1020;"></div>

<div class="datetimepicker datetimepicker-dropdown-bottom-right dropdown-menu" style="left: 286.533px; z-index: 1030;"></div>

<div class="datetimepicker datetimepicker-dropdown-bottom-right dropdown-menu" style="left: 647.467px; z-index: 1040;"></div>
```

Now if I update a record and the form refreshes, the above code duplicates. That is instead of 4 divs it duplicates to 8 divs and so on. If I continue making updates my browser freezes eventually due to too many duplicate divs on my DOM

I have tried to clear the DOM to no avail.
Any help PLEASE!!

Comment: what do you mean by "reloading the form with ajax" ? can you give us a code exemple ?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
 $(".dateElement").datetimepicker({
  format: "dd MM yyyy H:i",
  autoclose: true,
  todayBtn: true,
  showMeridian: 1
 });
</script>

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
 $(".dateElement").datetimepicker({
  format: "dd MM yyyy H:i",
  autoclose: true,
  todayBtn: true,
  showMeridian: 1
 });

This script get called when user clicks on any txtbox element used for date with the class "dateElement". Assuming there 2 txtbox elements used, say "Start Date" and "End Date", when the page is loaded and user clicks on "Start Date" form elemnt, this loads two divs with the name "dateTimpicker" on DOM. Nw, if another operatn occur, say "Update Rec" using ajax, this reloads only the form but the 2 divs becom 4 divs. I use Firebug
</script>

Comment: Using Firebug to view the "HTML" section, you ll notice the duplication every time the form with date components performs an operation using Jquery Ajax. See url where I got the plugin [HERE](http://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)

Comment: I'm not able to see snippet code, please fix it, also did you make your ajax to update it automatically or on request ? also one or two sections(from and to) so you pick date twice for each div or only one time? why you didn't do it as input why as div?